# c# Remove script tag from a string using regex

Tags: regex

I have a string which contains some data/script tags .I want to search the below script tag in the string based on url http://cdn.walkme.com/users and remove this specific script tag from the string

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function() {var walkme = document.createElement('script'); walkme.type = 'text/javascript'; walkme.async = true; walkme.src='http://cdn.walkme.com/users/cb643dab0d6f4c7cbc9d436e7c06f719/walkme_cb643dab0d6f4c7cbc9d436e7c06f719.js'; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(walkme, s); window._walkmeConfig = {smartLoad:true}; })();</script>
```

Comment: if you're looking for a way to disable walkme once per session, there is an easy way. Let me know if that's what you need

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a language where the regex supports *atomic* groups.

***Scraper Series***

Find
`<script(?:\s+(?>"[\S\s]*?"|'[\S\s]*?'|(?:(?!/>)[^>])?)+)?\s*>[\S\s]*?http://cdn\.walkme\.com/users[\S\s]*?</script\s*(?=>)>`

Replace ""

https://regex101.com/r/8ldMoN/1

Formatted / Comments

```
 <script                            # Open script tag
 (?:
      \s+ 
      (?>                           # REQUIRED Atomic group to get complete tag
           " [\S\s]*? "
        |  ' [\S\s]*? '
        |  (?:
                (?! /> )            # Not a self contained tag (why atomic is necessary)
                [^>] 
           )?
      )+
 )?
 \s* 
 > 
                                    # What we want to find
 [\S\s]*? http://cdn\.walkme\.com/users [\S\s]*?  

 </script \s*                       # Close script tag
 (?= > )
 >
```